# How would two brute squads fight?

Tags: 7th-sea

In 7th Sea, brutes deal damage to the more high profile characters based on their margin of success.

The reason I ask is because Henchmen/Villains/Heroes make raises for damage, and I see raising to hit another brute as essentially the same thing as a raise for damage against the brute health track.  Brutes obviously don't raise for damage (or that's an entirely new question) although on other rolls they can make raises as normal.

What happens if one brute squad attacks another?  Can they only knock one brute out from the target squad at a time, do they have to make raises, or does their MoS knock out extras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing some items the best option seems to be using the "Mass Fire Volley" system in the Montaigne book.  I create a Volley number based solely on the acting brute squad and the attack is the volley.  Since the rules for a firing line specifically say that each hit on a brute kills it, then I can mod it to just a KO since its not a firearm and thus count hits without having to number crunch, however minimized as it is already.  Each squad will roll on their actions as normal.

*A TR 2 squad has a volley of 8 at full strength, rolling 4 dice. each 8-10 is -1 brute from the target squad, "exploding" the 10's as normal*

Answer (score 5):

Other than calculating the dice pool differently ([*Members*] **k** [*Threat*] instead of [*Attribute + Skill*] **k** [*Attribute*]), brute squads attack like anyone else.

The margin of success stuff only factors in when they deal damage... And you don't deal damage when you attack another brute squad.

So one brute squad attacks another just like anyone else does: They take a number of raises, roll their to-hit, and, if successful, they knock out one brute in the opposing squad plus one brute per raise.

**Note:** The above is how the rules are written. If you have two brute squads slapping each other around, you might want to do something to speed up the process or switch to narrative mode.

Comment: If a Brute Squad attacks another Brute Squad, what would it have to do/roll to knock out more than one defending brute in that hit.  However, I've +1'd the answer for the "brutes should raise against brutes".  Just giving it a bit to see if there is other insight.